# Laravel cashier with stripe skipTrial() got some error

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

When I am using skipTrial() to swap plans but skip the trial period on the plan. I am getting some error given below.

**Controller**

```
public function skipTrialUpdate()
    {
        $user            = Auth::user();
        $user->subscription('main')->skipTrial()->swap(Input::get('plan'));

        return redirect(url('/home'))->with('skipTrialUpdatedNotice', 'You skipped trial and plan changed. Thanks');
    }
```

**Error**

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2258: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::skipTrial()
```

**Details**

```
in Builder.php line 2258
at Builder->__call('skipTrial', array())
at Builder->skipTrial()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'skipTrial'), array()) in Builder.php line 1340
at Builder->__call('skipTrial', array())
at Builder->skipTrial()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'skipTrial'), array()) in Model.php line 3493
at Model->__call('skipTrial', array()) in SubscriptionController.php line 37
at Subscription->skipTrial() in SubscriptionController.php line 37
at SubscriptionController->skipTrialUpdate()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(SubscriptionController), 'skipTrialUpdate'), array()) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('skipTrialUpdate', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(SubscriptionController), object(Route), 'skipTrialUpdate') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(SubscriptionController), object(Route), object(Request), 'skipTrialUpdate') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
```

Comment: I have laravel 5.2 and even if in the documentation that method is available, when you look the class it self the skipTrial method is not there Laravel\Cashier\Subscription.